# Fahrenheit or Celsius Python program keeps repeating

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to build a simple conversion between Celcius and Fahrenheit but I keep running into issues. If I run the program and type and hit enter nothing happens or else other errors. I'd really appreciate help and for you to explain as much as possible so I can learn.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit):
     celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)
     return celsius

def celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius):
   fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0) * celsius + 32.0
   return fahrenheit

print('Welcome')

userInput = 0

while userInput != 3 :
   userInput = input('''Main Menu 
   1:Fahrenheit to Celsius
   2:Celsius to Fahrenheit
   3:Exit program
   Please enter 1, 2 or 3:''')

if userInput == 1:
   fahren = input('\nPlease enter degrees Fahrenheit: ')

   try:
       fahren = float(fahren)
   except:
       print('Sorry, %s is not a valid number' % fahren)
       exit(1)
    
cels = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahren)

print('%s degrees Fahrenheit equals %d degrees Celsius' % fahren % cels)

elif userInput == 2:
    cels = input('\nPlease enter degrees Celsius: ')

    try:
        cels = float(cels)
    except:
        print('\nSorry, %s is not a valid number' % cels)
        exit(1)

    fahren = celsiusToFahrenheit(cels)

    else:
        print('Invalid entry')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is a mess, you need to get this right in Python for your code to run -- it's not optional.  Also:

- `userInput` is input as a `str` but tested as an `int`.  For the purpose at hand, either is valid but you have to be consistent.
- A user input of '3' causes a `'Invalid entry'` error message even though it's a valid option to leave the program.
- User option '2' never outputs its results before returning to the main menu.
- You should avoid a bare `except:` and instead specify the error (`ValueError`) you're trying to catch.
- This isn't valid syntax `print('%s ... %d ...' % fahren % cels)` for the `%` operator and since you tagged this *python-3.x*, you might want to use the `format()` function instead.

Below is my rework of your code addressing the above and other issues:

```
import sys

def fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit):
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9

def celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius):
    return 9/5 * celsius + 32

print("Welcome")

while True:
    userInput = int(input('''\nMain Menu
   1: Fahrenheit to Celsius
   2: Celsius to Fahrenheit
   3: Exit program
   Please enter 1, 2 or 3: '''))

    if userInput == 1:
        fahrenheit = input("\nPlease enter degrees Fahrenheit: ")

        try:
            fahrenheit = float(fahrenheit)
        except ValueError:
            sys.exit("Sorry, {} is not a valid number".format(fahrenheit))

        celsius = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit)

        print("{} degrees Fahrenheit equals {} degrees Celsius".format(fahrenheit, celsius))

    elif userInput == 2:
        celsius = input("\nPlease enter degrees Celsius: ")

        try:
            celsius = float(celsius)
        except ValueError:
            sys.exit("Sorry, {} is not a valid number".format(celsius))

        fahrenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius)

        print("{} degrees Celsius equals {} degrees Fahrenheit".format(celsius, fahrenheit))

    elif userInput == 3:
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid entry")
```

Comment: I don't think you should use `sys.exit` in case of a bad input; just `continue` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not automatically convert values received by `input()` to their respective type. (Python 2 did this, so the confusion may originate from there). So, the number you receive will still be an `str`. `"3"` is never equal to `3`. The easiest way is simply converting the input to a number by wrapping it in the `int` function:

```py
userInput = int(input('...'))
```

You should wrap it in `try`-`except` the same way you did with inputting the temperature - but be sure to add a `continue` statement. (All it does is to go to the beginning of the loop, effectively "retrying" input).

```py
try:
    userInput = int(input('...'))
except:
    print('Invalid number!')
    continue
```

A small thing you forgot is to indent the statements, beginning with `if userInput == 1`. This way, they would be executed outside the loop.

Comment: I updated the info and it got rid of the bug with the input but now it is throwing an indentation error when I fixed as you suggested.

Comment: What's the exact error?